# Restyling a div element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to restyle a div element so that any number is underlined with the click of a button. I am only using javascript not JQuery.

This is partially working but I cannot get past it . At the moment my code will only underscore a unique number and also it will not underscore numbers with more than one digit

My div contains text that reads as follows;

Here there is text that contains numbers such as     number 8 and number 9  or number 18

A button below this should allow the user to click and underscore all numbers in the text

```
<script>



 changeAll = function(){
 var myText = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
 for (var i=0; i<=1000; i++){
     myText = myText.replace(i, "<u>"+i+"</u>");
 }
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML=myText;
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of i because, there is no block scope in EC5. Var i is escaping the loop. Meaning it will only underscore the last index of the loop

You can either use a IIFE closure to capture i state

```
(function (i){
    //assign underscore
})(i)
```

Or you can try with

```
for (let i=0; i<=1000; i++){ //assign underscore }
```

Do notice not all browsers have the let keyword implemented. It is a EC6 feature

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your approach, is that after replacing single digit - you're changing the text, so you cannot find number anymore (number is already corrupted with tags).

The standard way is to use regexp, like this:

```js
var v = document.getElementById('txt').innerText;
v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/g, '<u>$1</u>');
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = v;
```

```html
<div id="txt">test 1 with 12 some 123 numbers</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , I like this approach

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping over the numbers, you can do it all at once with a regular expression

```js
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var text = myText.innerHTML;
myText.innerHTML = text.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<u>$1</u>');
```

```html
<p id="myText">
This is some 713 text with 8 a few numbers 99 in it.
</p>
```

The `(\d+)` matches one more more digits as a capturing group, and the `$1` in the replacement string uses the text captured in the group, surrounding it by the underline tags.

---

Note — the `<u>` tag is deprecated, and better practice is to mark something indicating *what* it is, not how you want it to look, so I would mark it as a number then use a CSS style to make things that are numbers be underlined:

```
text.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>'); // JS
.number { text-decoration: underline; }                   // CSS
```

Comment: Ah! Lashane posted essentially the same thing as I was writing.